# Generate a random value that doesn't exist in the same column

Tags: mysql, random, varchar

I already googled it, but I just found similar answers.
I'm not a back-end developer, so I don't know a lot of SQL. I need to generate and insert a 6 digit random value that involves numbers and characters (varchar, I think) that doesn't exist in the same column.

I tried this `FLOOR(RAND() * 401) + 100` that I found somewhere, but it just generate numbers and... nothing more.

I'm lost.

Please, masters of databases, light my way with your random numbers ;-;

Comment: You're going to hit the so called birthday paradox pretty fast with numbers in the range [100-500].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT LPAD(CONV(RAND() * POW(36, 6), 10, 36), 6, 0)
```

This will create a 6 character "random" alphanumeric value.

**But:**

- You will need to check if the value already exists in your table.
- The distribution is not equal, because rand() retuns a FLOAT which only has  a precision of 23 bit, while POW(36, 6) needs something like 32 bit.

**Update:**

However - because you will need to check, if the value already exists, you better create the number in PHP.

```php
$success = false;
while (!$success) {
    $rndInt = rand(0, pow(36, 6) - 1);
    $rndStr = base_convert ($rndInt, 10, 36);
    $rndStr = str_pad($rndStr , 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE your_column = {$rndStr} LIMIT 1";
    $db->query($query);
    if (!$db->fetchColumn()) { // value does not exist yet
        // insert new random value
        $query = "INSERT INTO your_table (your_column) VALUES ({$rndStr})";
        $db->query($query);
        $success = true; // will terminate the loop
    } else { // value already exists
        // do nothing - try again in the next loop
    }
}
```

You will need to ajust the code to what ever you use for MySQL communication.

Comment: It worked, but I really don't know how to check if the value exist :(

Comment: Do it on application site. What language do you use? You will need some kind of loop

Comment: I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Does the value have any security issues? It looks like a TAN.

Comment: No, it doesn't. And I don't have idea what is TAN.

Comment: In MySQL RAND() returns IEEE 754 64-bit `DOUBLE` values, as do most floating point computations in the dbms engine.  That carries a 52-bit mantissa, so the distribution of numbers should be acceptable when RAND() is multiplied by 36^6.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. Solved! :)

Comment: Thanks @OllieJones - I didn't know that. Do you know any official reference? I could only find "floating-point value".

Comment: @OllieJones, i should have see that myself. Thanks again.

Comment: what if it does exists in database then you will generate another random number and what if it again matches in database  so i suggest you create a callback function loop that will be keep executing until it gets a non matching key however it will be kinda slow and fast deepening on callbacks

Comment: @VikasKandari There are 2176782336 (more than 2 billions) possible values. If you have already generated one billion values, you will need an average of two iterations to get a free one. However, when you are going to have billions of such values in the table, you should use more than 6 caracters.

Comment: So the worst case scenario is infinity, correct? there is a chance that random returned is something that already exists and therefore would need another number. The worst case would be when all numbers generated are which already exist.

Comment: And at 50% capacity you're calling it 2-5x time at least for avg case. But at 80%, you're just spinning your wheels at that point. Must be great that entire program depends on Math.random()... would you fly in a plane where algo is basically rand num generator?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, As per question: Randomness is a requirement - not a problem. And please check your math. At 50% you need on avg. 2 iterations. At 80% you need 5. The chance not to find a "free" number at 80% after 1000 iterations is 1 to 8*10^96. And as I wrote in another comment : If your table is close to be full (> 10%) you should use longer strings.

Answer (score 0):

**A tweaked version**

```
$success = false;
while (!$success) {
$rndInt = rand(0, pow(36, 6) - 1);
$rndStr = base_convert ($rndInt, 10, 36);
$rndStr = str_pad($rndStr , 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
//checking duplicate records
$checking_duplicate_records = $dbConn->query("SELECT  COUNT(your_column) as 
duplicate 
FROM `your_table` 
WHERE your_column IN ('$rndStr')");
    while($row = $checking_duplicate_records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if (!$row['duplicate'] > 0) { // value does not exist yet        
    $success = true; // will terminate the loop
    echo $rndStr; //your unique value
    } else { // value already exists
    // do nothing - try again in the next loop
}
}
}
```